# Why doesn't `1` fit into a decimal(4, 4) column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal

I have a `decimal(4, 4)` column in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  If I understand correctly, that means:

- `Precision` of 4, ie up to four digits can be stored after the decimal place
- `Scale` of 4, ie a a total of four digits can be stored

When I run an update command to set the column to `1` (`update myTable set myDecimalColumn=1`), I get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

I don't understand how that is true.  `1` has no digits after the decimal and is only one digit long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Precision` specifies the total number of digits that can be stored, the `Scale` specifies, how many of those digits live behind the decimal point.

A `DECIMAL(4,4)` therefore has four digits and all are behind the decimal point. That means you can store values form -0.9999 to 0.9999. You cannot store -1 or 1 as they have a digit before the decimal point.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18722)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CAST(-0.9999 as DECIMAL(4,4)),CAST(0.123456 as DECIMAL(4,4)),CAST(0.9999 as DECIMAL(4,4))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18722/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 |
----------------------------------
|  -0.9999 |   0.1235 |   0.9999 |
```

To store 1 you have to add an additional digit as in `DECIMAL(5,4)`. That allows you to store values from -9.9999 to 9.9999:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18722)

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT CAST(-9.9999 as DECIMAL(5,4)),CAST(1 as DECIMAL(5,4)),CAST(9.9999 as DECIMAL(5,4))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18722/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 | COLUMN_1 | COLUMN_2 |
----------------------------------
|  -9.9999 |        1 |   9.9999 |
```

Comment: I didn't realize scale was *exclusively* after the decimal.  I thought it was *up to* that number after the decimal.